override sub dependencies in vcpkg
I am using vcpkg in manifest mode in CMake, by setting the toolset in the CMakeLists.txt.
I have as a dependency VTK and that has also a Qt dependency, but I am also using Qt in my own project. How can I make so that vcpkg uses the Qt installed in my system instead of compiling it?
I've tried setting the VCPKG_ENV_PASSTHROUGH to the Qt install dirs but nothing happenes, VTK has Qt as a dependency in it's vcpkg.json
